# Improving performance of ifstream in c++

Tags: c++

I apologize if this question is a bit vague or just plain stupid, I am still very much a novice.

I need to extract information from a web log file in c++. The string manipulations are relatively, accessing the data in a timely fashion isn't. 
What I am doing currently

`string str;`

`ifstream fh("testlog.log",ios::in);`

`while (getline(fh,str));`

From here I get the useful data from the string. This works fine for a log file with 100 entries, but takes forever on a log file with million+ entries.
Any help would greatly be appreciated

Comment: Just for testing, could you try using `fgets` ? Open the file with `fopen` and then something like `while(fgets(cstr, 256, fp))`. Tell us what your results are (how long it takes).

Comment: Have you profiled to see where the bottleneck is? If it's disk, nothing in code is going to fix that, per se. (If your CPU time is not dwarfed by IO time, you could multithread.)

Answer (score 2):

I really suspect that I/O is hurting you more than `ifstream` here. Have you checked to see that you're actually CPU bound? Most likely you're having disk and cache locality issues.

There may not be a lot you can do in that case.

If it is CPU bound have you profiled to see where the CPU time is going?

Comment: I know this question is old, but giving answers such as "disk" and "cache locality" as issues to someone who has said they are a novice, without explaining, and asking for profiling, isn't the most effective imo

Answer (score 2):

After wasting hours and hours of my time, I compiled the same code in Quincy2005 instead of Microsoft Visual studio. The result was dramatic. From a 40min execution time to 1 min. The some improvement can accomplished in Microsoft Visual Studio by passing a pointer of the filehandler to the getline function. On a Linux based system it takes about 40 sec to execute. I cursed Microsoft for a good 40 min for wasting my time.

Answer (score 1):

Here the fastest way I found to extract a file :

```
std::ifstream file("test.txt", std::ios::in | std::ios::end);

std::size_t fileSize = file.tellg();

std::vector<char> buffer(fileSize);

file.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);

file.read(buffer.data(), fileSize);

std::string str(buffer.begin(), buffer.end());
```

Yet, if your file is really that big, I strongly suggest you to manipulate it as a stream...

Comment: Ok what I have done is obtained filesize, like you have done. divided the value by 2, seems like the is to big for 1 dynamic array. Reading the chars into a string seems to be wasting all the time. So I suppose I could try and read each line from the array without the help of string functions. It just seems a bit messy

Answer (score 1):

@Errata:

are you sure, that your code would be faster than say:

```
std::ifstream in("test.txt");
in.unsetf(std::ios::skipws);
std::string contents;
std::copy(
        std::istream_iterator<char>(in),
        std::istream_iterator<char>(),
        std::back_inserter(contents));
```

Also, the OP wants linewise access, which would conveniently be done:

```
std::ifstream in("test.txt");
in.unsetf(std::ios::skipws);
size_t count = std::count_if(
        std::istream_iterator<std::string>(in),
        std::istream_iterator<std::string>(),
        &is_interesting);
std::cout << "Interesting log lines: " << count << std::endl;
```

of course define a predicate, e.g.

```
static bool is_interesting(const std::string& line)
{ 
    return std::string::npos != line.find("FATAL");
}
```